# Extracting a part of a string in php

Tags: php, string, strip

I have a specific need to strip characters from a PHP input.

For example, we have a version number and I only need the last part of it.

Given `14.1.2.123` I only need `123`
Given `14.3.21` I only need the `21`

Is there a way that I can get just those numbers in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$temp = explode('.', $version); // explode by (.)
echo $temp[count($temp) - 1]; // get the last element

echo end($temp);
```

Or

```
$pos = strrpos($version, '.'); // Get the last (.)'s position
echo substr(
     $version, 
     ($pos + 1), // +1 to get the next position
     (strlen($version) - $pos) // the length to be extracted
); // Extract the part
```

[strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php), [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: I was adding `strrpos` answer but got 5 sec late :) +1

Comment: `echo end($temp);`

Comment: Great @Dagon. Missed that 1. :)

Comment: Legendary! Worked like a charm.Thank you all